# How to make html menu become responsive on mobile?

Tags: html, css

My menu is not working correctly in mobile view.

How do I fix my responsive view for the menu?

This is the code sample in fiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/wa18un0e/

```
<div class="menu">
<ul id="sf-menu">          
    <li class="current">
        <a href="#" id="menu_admin_viewAdminModule" class="firstLevelMenu">
            <b>Dashboard</b>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span id="separator_level1"><b> | </b> </span>
    </li>           `enter code here`
    <li>
        <a href="#" id="menu_pim_viewPimModule" class="firstLevelMenu">
           <b>New Service</b>
        </a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span id="separator_level1"><b> | </b> </span>
    </li>       
</div>
```

Comment: have you check out bootstrap? http://getbootstrap.com/

Comment: You can use Bootstrap or jQuery mobile :)

Comment: i have checked bootstrap but im not so familiar with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this is you css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .menu{height: auto;}
    .menu > ul > li > ul > li , .menu > ul , .menu > ul > li   {float: none;margin: 0;}
    .menu > ul > li > a{border-radius: 0;}
    .menu > ul > li > ul > li:nth-child(even) , .menu > ul > li:nth-child(even){display: none;}
    .menu > ul > li > ul{width: 100%;height: auto;;padding: 5px 0;}
}
```

Comment: thx with this i manage to make the main menu become responsive but however the sub menu will become overlapping instead of pushing the menu to the bottom

Comment: Remove the `position:absolute`.

Comment: tried that already previously, i didnt remove it because the menu will drag down eventhough didnt select the menu and also effect in desktop view

Answer (score 1):

Buddy,
Please remember below things for not only to display navigation(menu) in mobile, whatever element to sit perfectly in mobile, you should remember below things.

1) Your website should focus on the applying the styles on mobile first basis
2) Then your styles should be perfectly set, taking into the consideration, the mobile device width.

**Step-1:**
Displaying mobile first layout is simply to avoid more http requests!
Just add the below line to head part

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

This will make mobile to display the page to the total width.

[Please check here for more details](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/set-the-viewport#ensure-an-accessible-viewport)
**NOTE:** This will make our styling navigation(menu) for mobile easier.

**Step-2:**
After 'step-1', you should load perfect stylesheet to display the navigation perfect on the mobile, you should use

```
@media (query) {
  /* CSS Rules used when query matches */
}
```

Example

```
@media (min-width: 500px) and (max-width: 600px) {
(This tells us to apply style when viewport width falls between 500px & 600px)
            h1 {
              color: fuchsia;
            }
    }
```

Please go through the below links for further guidance & adopting a menu navigation specially for the mobile.

[Simple Mobile navigation](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2013/04/17/slide-and-push-menus/)
[Mobile menu design guide](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/principles/menus-short)
[Some menu designs to tweak in](http://exisweb.net/incredibly-useful-list-of-responsive-navigation-and-menu-patterns)

***DISCLAIMER:*** As the answer needs more explanation, I am directing you to the links, if you got any problem, please drop the one here! We will help!